# The graph is not drawn in the matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, fft

I'm drawing a graph in the matplotlib by converting to FFT with Arduino data. However, the same error does not cause a graph. I think it's because of self in update() what should I do? I don't know how to change when there is a Typeerror in my code. If you find a problem, can you tell me? 
+ I solved the error. However, the graph is not printed. The code has been modified as a whole. What happen?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import*
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import datetime
import serial
import time
import random
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import animation
from collections import deque  # import a "circular" list
from threading import Thread, Lock

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1212, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.widget = matplotlibWidget()
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.widget, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.centralwidget.setLayout(self.gridLayout)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
#from matplotlibwidgetFile import matplotlibWidget

class matplotlibWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        self.i = 0
        self.data = []
        lock = Lock()        

        freq = 2000              # 1/T
        self.guarda = 100           # 200
        r = range(0, int(freq/2+1), int(freq/self.guarda))
        self.frequencia = np.fft.fftfreq(self.guarda, d=1/freq)
        self.acelx = deque([], maxlen=self.guarda)

        self.fig = plt.figure()
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)  
        self.right_layout = QVBoxLayout() 
        self.right_layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.setLayout(self.right_layout)
        self.ax.set_xlim((0,int(freq/2)))
        self.ax.set_ylim((0,1000))
        self.line, = self.ax.plot([],[])
        self.ax.grid(True)


        def data_input():
            for line in arduinoData:
                try:
                    self.i+=1
                    self.acelx.append(float(line))
                    with lock:
                        if self.i > len(self.acelx):
                            self.data = np.fft.fft(self.acelx)
                except ValueError:
                    pass
        t = Thread(target=data_input)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

        S = Scope(self.line,self.frequencia, self.guarda, self.data, self.ax, self.acelx, self.i )
        timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        timer.timeout.connect(S.update)
        timer.start(0)

class Scope(matplotlibWidget) : 
    def __init__(self, line, frequencia, guarda, data, ax, acelx, i) :
        self.line, = line,
        self.ax = ax
        self.frequencia = frequencia
        self.guarda = guarda
        self.data = data
        self.acelx = acelx
        self.i = i

    def update(self) :

        if self.i > len(self.acelx) :
            self.line.set_data(self.frequencia[:int(self.guarda/2)], abs(np.real(self.data[:int(self.guarda/2)])))
            self.ax.figure.canvas.draw()

        return (self.line,)           



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    value = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    arduinoData = serial.Serial('com5', 9600)
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create instance:

```
s = Scope()
timer = QtCore.QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(s.update)
```

or

```
timer = QtCore.QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(Scope().update)
```

Comment: thank you for answer. But It is not working. A new error has occurred.Exception has occurred: TypeError
__init__() missing 7 required positional arguments: 'line', 'frequencia', 'guarda', 'data', 'ax', 'acelx', and 'i'

Comment: Right, you have to pass them to the Scope

Comment: You declared them here:
class Scope(matplotlibWidget) : 
    def __init__(self, line, frequencia, guarda, data, ax, acelx, i)

Comment: I solved the error. However, the graph is not printed. The code has been modified as a whole. The modified code has been re-uploaded.

Comment: You have to post your error code, full text. I don't have arduino, so I can't guess your problem )

Comment: now I don't have error this code. what should i do? ㅠㅠ